# Different timer accuracy when using different intervals

Tags: c#, .net, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inaccurate .NET timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841719/inaccurate-net-timer)

Here is my code:

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer((o) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss:fff"));
    }, null, (1000 - DateTime.Now.Millisecond), 1000);
```

Here is what (approximatly) I receive when It runs:

```
50:17:005
50:18:018
50:19:032
50:20:046
50:21:060
50:22:074
50:23:088
50:24:102
50:25:116
50:26:131
50:27:144
50:28:158
//and so on. Apparently there is a splice to 5-15 ms for each tick
```

When I change my ticktime to 998 (only 2 ms different!!!) I receive the next:

```
48:52:001
48:52:999
48:53:997
48:54:996
48:55:993
48:56:991
48:57:989
48:58:987
48:59:985
49:00:983
49:01:981
49:02:979
//and so on. Apparently that timer ticks almost perfectly!
```

My question is: Why such behavior is observed? Why only 2 ms of difference and such great difference in accuracy?

Comment: Tip: Don't use "WTF" in the question title and only use one question or exclamation mark at a time if you want good answers.

Comment: What you're trying to do is the equivalent of measuring a board of unknown length *with a ruler of unknown length about the same size as the board*. Clearly you are not going to get good results if you do that! To measure the exact imprecision of a low-precision timer you need to use a *high-precision timer*. **Use StopWatch to measure the precision of Timer.**

Answer (score 2):

What you see is not a difference in accuracy, it's just that you have chosen a timer interval where the accuracy limitation is less visible.

The clock runs at a frequency that is lower than 1000 Hz. On your system it seems to be about 70 Hz. If you happen to choose a timer interval that triggers just before the clock, you will see a small difference, but if you have a timer interval that triggers just after the clock, it will run on the next clock tick every time and you see a large difference.